# Melhor plataforma de Backend para microsserviços

Tags: docker, haskell, microsserviços, clojure

tenho que desenvolver um servidor com microsserviços com alguma linguagem de programação funcional, inicialmente pensei em Haskell e Clojure (linguagens com quem mais me identifico), preciso de uma linguagem com resposta rápida e que tenha uma maior facilidade em desenvolvimento em microsserviços. Qual dessas linguagens traria uma melhor custo/beneficio (principalmente em questão de desempenho)?

Comment: Não pensa em desenvolver em PHP ou Nodejs?

Comment: Não, pro meu trabalho necessita ser uma linguagem funcional

Comment: Nunca usei Haskell para microserviços, mas gosto muito de Clojure com [Pedestal](http://pedestal.io/). Se seu benefício é performance, eu sugiro fortemente [actix-web](https://actix.rs/) do Rust, ele tem tido os melhores benchmarks entre todos os web servers. Rust é fácil de fazer ser [funcional (em pt)](https://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-rust-funcional-concorrente).
[em ingles](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/functional-programming-in-rust-part-1/)